# Send value to worker thread PyQt?

Tags: python, multithreading, arduino, pyqt, pyserial

I'm just learning to program GUI's with PyQt. The GUI that I'm trying to make sends a value too an Arduino with the Pyserial library. I got it working but after a few sends the GUI freezes.
I read somewhere that threading can solve this, so I tried this but I can't figure out how to send a value too the working thread from the main thread. For example I want to send the number 123 too the working thread. How do I go about this?

Comment: Please, add a snippet of your code for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a parameter to a `QThread` when initializing it, like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class FooThread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self, foo):
        super(FooThread, self).__init__()
        self.foo = foo

    def run(self):
        print self.foo    

def main():

        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) 
        foo_thread = FooThread('foo')
        foo_thread.start()
        foo_thread.finished.connect(QtGui.qApp.exit)
        sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This snippet will create a PyQt application and then starts a thread that prints out the parameter that is passed to its constructor (in the example above it prints `foo`), then terminates the execution of the application.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey, This method actually worked. There was also something wrong in my Arduino code. Still wondering if there is a way where you don't have to open the thread everytime you sent a value. Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Konnenhom Actually I think I can suggest you a solution for that one as well if you want.

Comment: That would be great!

Comment: @Mr.Konnenhom check this out: http://pythonfiddle.com/serialthreadgui . Hope that's what you are looking for.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for your help!